# List all the indices that has a error message in a nested list R

Tags: r, mclapply

I am using `mclapply` to run my code in parallel. Below is a snippet of my code. When I set `mc.preschedule = FALSE`, it stores the error and goes to next item in the list. I want to see what all the elements in the list has a associated error message.

```
OutputList = mclapply(Users.list,TestFunction,mc.cores = 25,mc.preschedule = FALSE)
```

Below is the error message for one of the item in a list.

```
`Jack`
[1] "Error in TestFunction(DF, x) : \n  Nodes in query cannot be found in the input graph.\n\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in TestFunction(DF, x): Nodes in query cannot be found in the input graph.
```

Is there a way I can list all the indices that contains any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
which(mapply(inherits, OutputList, 'try-error'))
```